# Pyspark using lpad not accepting length function

Tags: pyspark, casting, string-length, lpad

I am trying to add a prefix to a string column 'data' value with:

```
`df.select('data_id',lpad(df['data'],length(df.data) +3 ,'p1/'))`
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

I tried casting with `int(length(df.data))`, but the message was

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'

I also tried `.cast("integer")` and I got a similar error.

Additionally, I need to add the prefix just under a condition where 'data_id' is under an interval, like [1 .. 100]. Can you help me?

Comment: try `df.select('data_id', F.expr("""lpad(data,length(data)+3,'p1/'))"""))`

Comment: I got a "ParseException: u"\nextraneous input ')' ..."

Comment: there was an extra bracket by mistake. try this `df.select('data_id', F.expr("""lpad(data,length(data)+3,'p1/')"""))`

Comment: also import functions like, from `pyspark.sql import functions as F` or `from pyspark.sql.functions import expr`

Comment: for what u want u could also do, `df.select("data_id",F.concat(F.lit('p1/'),F.col("data")))`

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi it works with `concat`. Thanks!